# Stack Exchange misspelled on almost every page of the network

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, stack-exchange

The problem is a little bit less serious than the title says, but is is a misspelling anyway.

As [the official page tells us](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance), the correct spelling is Stack Exchange, i.e. with a space between Stack and Exchange. But I find the space very hard to see in the black header that is on top of (almost?) every page in the Network:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but due to the sidebar getting wider, something had to give....

Comment: @rene, you are making a joke, right?

Comment: It is not Friday anymore, so maybe I'm seriously joking ...

Comment: [This is the official logo though...](http://stackexchange.com/about/logos)

Comment: Rather than using a space as a word separator, they're using color. Besides, it's a _logo_, and logos don't necessarily need to follow grammar conventions.

Comment: @hichris123 I really hadn't thought that a company would misspell their own name in their own logo.

Comment: Could be worse. Could be Starnexchange.

Comment: This is logo, no bug here.

Comment: It's not misspelled. It's stylized.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Logos don't care about word spacing. Actually, this "grammar" mistake is quite explicit as seen here on the official page of [Stack Exchange logos](https://stackexchange.com/about/logos).

As the developers are using the logo as the icon, the spacing was never necessary. Also, you can see the two words are "separated" by the use of colors and that you know it is supposed to say Stack Exchange. No bug here, [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)